# Maximum number of lists

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

- Do you know if there is a maximum number of lists you can have in one SharePoint 2013 site ?
- Or a least the maximum number of lists you can use without having performance issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no maximum number of list limitation. You are limited by other value of 60 million items per content database.

if you have more than 60 million items you need to use multiple content dbs and multiple site collections.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#ContentDB

There are other factors which may limit how many lists you have, If you are using custom permission in each list you may hit performance issues.